# onchange event show all text values of target element, why?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Consider this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
   <script>

      $(function(){

           $("select").change(function(){

                 var val = $(this).val();
                 var text = $(this).text();

                 // That's fine
                 alert(val);

                 // But it's not. It alerts both Value 1 and Value 2
                 alert(text);
           });
      }); 

   </script>
</head>
<body>

 <select>
    <option value="val_1">Value 1</option>
    <option value="val_2">Value 2</option>
 </select>


</body>
</html>
```

When `onchange` event occurs, then it alerts the right value of target `option` element (val_1 or val_2). That's fine.

But the problem with options's text. That should alert either Value 1 or Value 2, but not both! So what's the problem? Why it alerts both values, when only one target option element is processed?

```js
  $(function(){

           $("select").change(function(){

                 var val = $(this).val();
                 var text = $(this).text();

                 // That's fine
                 alert(val);

                 // But it's not. It alerts both Value 1 and Value 2
                 alert(text);
           });
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

 <select>
    <option value="val_1">Value 1</option>
    <option value="val_2">Value 2</option>
 </select>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

In your change event, `this` refers to the `<select>` element, not the selected `<option>`, therefore calling `.text()` on a select, will show all options.

To get the selected option text:

```
var text = $(this).find("option:selected").text();
```

```js
$(function(){

           $("select").change(function(){

                 var val = $(this).val();
                  var text = $(this).find("option:selected").text();

                 // That's fine
                 alert(val);

                 // But it's not. It alerts both Value 1 and Value 2
                 alert(text);
           });
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 
</head>
<body>

 <select>
    <option value="val_1">Value 1</option>
    <option value="val_2">Value 2</option>
 </select>


</body>
</html>
```